# Apache/httpd 2.4: Ignore authorization header when caching

Tags: apache, caching, authorization

I'm running a file server using Apache/httpd 2.4. I have completely overhauled the default directory listing, providing more info for each file, giving it a thumbnail and new file-type icon.

I have a couple personal folders, so I decided to lock those behind a basic authorization wall. Unfortunately this completely disables all caching.

Basically, I need `mod_cache` to ignore the `Authorization` header if possible.

I've tried `RequestHeader unset * early`, which seems to allow caching but only returns a cached response when the resource was cached without the `Authorization` header previously. Also `CacheIgnoreHeaders *` only disables caching headers on the response, it does nothing with the request.

```
X-Cache
    MISS from 127.0.1.1
X-Cache-Detail
    "Authorization required" from 127.0.1.1
```

Any suggestions? Let me know if you need more information.

Apache/httpd v2.4.52
Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish

Comment: Do you find a workaround ?